# Get the values of all of a elements with the same class following a certain class

Tags: jquery, class, dictionary

I am trying to get the values of nested elements with the same class which follow a certain class.

```
<li class="selected">
  <a class="hello">A</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="hello">B</a>
</li>
<li class="selected">
  <a class="hello">C</a>
</li>
```

So, I want to get 'A', 'C' with the following JQuery.

```
var values = $('.selected > .hello').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

I can get 'A', 'B', 'C' if I just use $('.hello').map(....).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is almost correct. The problem is because you're using `val()` yet `a` elements do not have a `value` property. Use `text()` instead:

```js
var values = $('.selected > .hello').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="selected">
    <a class="hello">A</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="hello">B</a>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    <a class="hello">C</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var values = $('li.selected > .hello').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="selected">
  <a class="hello">A</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a class="hello">B</a>
</li>
<li class="selected">
  <a class="hello">C</a>
</li>
So, I want to get 'A', 'C' with the following JQuery.
```

Use `li.selected` since second li has no class it will be excluded